# SuiteCommerce Advanced page error - Cannot read property "length" from null

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitecommerce

I have some problems in E-Commerce website development through NetSuite. Am getting an error when I tried to go `Setup -> SuiteCommerce Advanced -> Configuration` page it displays below error. I think it is from user privilege issue may be.

[image]

I am new to `NetSuite`, please someone help me how can I get rid of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you solved the issue?

Comment: No still I have this issue @AnupChaudhary

Comment: try to deploy default version, enable all required configuration from setup-->company should solve your problem, let me know.

Comment: No @AnupChaudhary Still I geet error. I am using sandbox account